# String.Join not working with vbCrLf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have the following procedure, which works fine. The only part that I am having an issue with is when the **CompNames list** has more than 1 record. I am trying to use **String.Join** with vbCrLf but it doesnt work.

Anyone have any ideas or an alternative I could use.

```
Public Sub gvTeamList_OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    Dim TeamID As Integer

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        TeamID = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "TeamID")
        Dim sSQL As String
        sSQL = "SELECT C.CompetitionName, CTT.TeamID " & _
                "FROM tblCompetition C " & _
                "left join  tblCompetitionToTeam CTT on C.CompetitionID = CTT.CompetitionID " & _
                "left join  tblTeam T on CTT.TeamID = T.TeamID " & _
                "where CTT.TeamID = " & TeamID
        Dim dr = DataClass.GetDataReader(sSQL)
        Dim bRows As Boolean = dr.HasRows
        Dim CompNames As New List(Of String)
        While dr.Read
            CompNames.Add(dr("CompetitionName"))
        End While
        Dim Name As String
        If CompNames.Count > 0 Then
            For Each Name In CompNames
                e.Row.Cells(5).Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, CompNames.ToArray)
            Next
        End If
        'e.Row.Cells(5).Text = 
        e.Row.Cells(5).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
        e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = Drawing.Color.DarkBlue
        dr.Close()
    End If

End Sub
```

I have also tried **Environment.NewLine** and that doesnt work either

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: you can check about problem [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-join)

Comment: It appears this is a `WebForms` application, so I have added the tag.  Please try to include information about the application environment (windows app vs web) in your tags, because this is an important distinction.

Comment: I assume `OnRowDataBound` is the `RowDataBound` handler of a `GridView`. Note that this is called for every row in the `GridView`, not just once. So your code is at least unefficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I think OP is aware - the query has a condition that changes for every row as well (`TeamID`), so the data is relevant to each specific row.  But it could be improved by loading the whole table at once into memory, and then querying the in-memory collection for the data specific to a team.

Comment: Out of scope of your question - please use parameterized queries. Concatenating values to form your SQL statement is bad practice and a security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using a WebForms application.  In HTML, a line return generally has no effect because whitespace is ignored (unless it's embedded in certain tags).  You want to use `<br />` to generate a line break:

```
e.Row.Cells(5).Text = String.Join("<br />", CompNames.ToArray)
```

Also, you don't need the `For Each` loop, because `String.Join` enumerates the entire array in a single call.  It's redundant to run this once for each Name in `CompNames`.